# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for Expectation of N random variables

Tags: probability, expectation

I have seen many books that state and prove the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for two, positive-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$ with bounded expectation as
\begin{equation}
E[XY]^2\le E[X^2]E[Y^2].
\end{equation}

Can we extend this definition to $N>2$ random variables such that 
\begin{equation}
E \left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N} X_n Y_n \right] ^2 \le E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N} X_n^2 \right] E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{N} Y_n^2 \right], 
\end{equation}
where all expectations are bounded? Could you suggest me a reference for this?

Comment: that can't be right. the correct cauchy schwarz is $E[XY]^2 \le E[X^2] E[Y^2]$.

Comment: thanks, just fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cauchy Schwarz inequality applied to the random vectors $x=(X_1,\dots X_N)$
 and $y=(Y_1,\dots Y_N)$ gives the pointwise bound
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N X_n Y_n\right|=|\langle x,y\rangle| \leq \|x\|\,\|y\|. \tag1$$
Combine (1) and your first inequality (with $X=\|x\|$ and $Y=\|y\|$) to obtain
\begin{eqnarray*}\left|E\left(\sum_{n=1}^N X_n Y_n\right)\right|
&\leq& E\left(\left|\sum_{n=1}^N X_n Y_n\right|\right)\\[5pt]
&\leq& E(\|x\|\|y\|)\\[5pt]
&\leq& E(\|x\|^2)^{1/2}\,E(\|y\|^2)^{1/2}\\[5pt] 
&=&E\left(\sum_{n=1}^N X_n^2\right)^{1/2}\,E\left(\sum_{n=1}^N Y_n^2\right)^{1/2}.\end{eqnarray*}
Now square both sides of the inequality to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Sure; just define the random variables $(X, Y)$ so that with probability $1/n$, $(X, Y) = (X_i, Y_i)$ for each $i$. Then your original Cauchy-Schwarz inequality reduces to your new one.

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is to let $(X,Y) = (X_n,Y_n)$ with probability $1/N$; $X=X_n$ with probability $1/N$ and $Y=Y_n$ with probability $1/N$ so that $E [XY] ^2 = \frac{1}{N^2} E [\sum_{n=1}^{N} X_nY_n ]^2$ and so on?

Comment: Yes; then after cancelling a factor of 1/N^2 from both sides, you should have what you want.